# jquery show hide div based on select value dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a project I am working on that needs to show/hide a division dependent on a selection.
I need that in selecting hiding divas of my desired group. Initially, the number and amount of   do not know! Currently it works for #selectField_1 and box_1. But
I do not want to do a static script I want to make it dynamic

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (value) {
        $('.box_1').hide();

        $('#51').show(); <==================Need Selected value from <select> as Default

        $('#selectField_1').change(function () {
            $('.box_1').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
</script>

<select id="selectField_1">
    <option value="51" selected>option1</option>
    <option value="52">option2</option>
    <option value="53">option3</option>
    <option value="54">option4</option>
</select>

<select id="selectField_2">
    <option value="55" selected>option1</option>
    <option value="56">option2</option>
    <option value="57">option3</option>
    <option value="58">option4</option>
</select>

.......................................

<select id="selectField_n">
    <option value="n" selected>option1</option>
    <option value="n">option2</option>
    <option value="n">option3</option>
    <option value="n">option4</option>
</select>

</br> 

<div id="51" class="box_1">Content 51</div>
<div id="52" class="box_1">Content 52</div>
<div id="53" class="box_1">Content 53</div>
<div id="54" class="box_1">Content 54</div>

<div id="55" class="box_2">Content 55</div>
<div id="56" class="box_2">Content 56</div>
<div id="57" class="box_2">Content 57</div>
<div id="58" class="box_2">Content 58</div>

...........................................

<div id="n" class="box_n">Content n</div>
<div id="n" class="box_n">Content n</div>
<div id="n" class="box_n">Content n</div>
<div id="n" class="box_n">Content n</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at delegated events in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a class on dropdowns:

```
<select id="selectField_1" class="SelectField">
        <option value="51" selected>option1</option>
        <option value="52">option2</option>
        <option value="53">option3</option>
        <option value="54">option4</option>
</select>
```

you have to do like this:

```
$('.SelectField').each(function(){
    $('.box_'+this.id.split('_')[1]).hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});

$('.SelectField').change(function () {
    $('.box_'+this.id.split('_')[1]).hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ALdSE/)

Comment: I did as you said, but he immediately displays all div

Comment: what you mean on page load all will be visible

Comment: When you load the page should be displayed only (selected)

Comment: I tried to check the code on the local machine. But he did not work

Answer (score 0):

For setting option by its value, you need to use:

```
$('#selectField_1 option[value="51"]');
```

and for selecting it:

```
$('#selectField_1 option[value="51"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do like this:

```
<select id="selectField_1">
    <option value="51" class="selected">option1</option>
    <option value="52">option2</option>
    <option value="53">option3</option>
    <option value="54">option4</option>
</select>
```

And in your js:

```
$("#your_select_id").find("option.selected").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ehsaan Sajjad said Apply Class on dropdowns to access all dropdowns with single selector like

```
<select id="selectField_1" class="ddlClass">
    <option value="51" selected>option1</option>
    <option value="52">option2</option>
    <option value="53">option3</option>
    <option value="54">option4</option>
</select>
<select id="selectField_2" class="ddlClass">
    <option value="55" selected>option1</option>
    <option value="56">option2</option>
    <option value="57">option3</option>
    <option value="58">option4</option>
</select>
```

And add one more class to your divs to hide all the divs by default like

```
<div id="51" class="box_1 boxdiv">Content 51</div>
<div id="52" class="box_1 boxdiv">Content 52</div>
<div id="53" class="box_1 boxdiv">Content 53</div>
<div id="54" class="box_1 boxdiv">Content 54</div>

<div id="55" class="box_2 boxdiv">Content 55</div>
<div id="56" class="box_2 boxdiv">Content 56</div>
<div id="57" class="box_2 boxdiv">Content 57</div>
<div id="58" class="box_2 boxdiv">Content 58</div>
```

And in the CSS write

```
.boxdiv{ display: none;}
```

Now your jQuery code will look like

```
$('.ddlClass').change(function () {

        $('.box_'+this.id.split('_')[1]).hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });
```